# CMake post-build output command with print

Tags: c, cmake, clion, cmake-custom-command

I'm using CLion 1.2 to build an embedded C project for an STM32 target. Cross compilation using GNU ARM tools works well, however, I would like to run `arm-none-eabi-size` after the executable file has been built, and have the output of that command be printed to the build output window.

I have had a thorough look at the `add_custom_command` macro, however, I do not intend on generating an output file, which is what the macro appears to do.

Below is the `CMakeLists.txt` that I am using in the project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
include(CMakeForceCompiler)
project(rtos_clion)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR cortex-m0)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)

# Target Environment
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/4.9 2015q2")

# Cross compiler
CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(arm-none-eabi-gcc GNU)
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(arm-none-eabi-g++ GNU)

# Executable type
set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".elf")

# Compiler flags
set(ARM_FLAGS "-mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -Os")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${ARM_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11 -fabi-version=0 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fno-threadsafe-statics -ffunction-sections -g")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=gnu11 ${ARM_FLAGS} -ffunction-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -Wall -Wextra -g")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${ARM_FLAGS} -g -Wl,--library-path=\"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}\" -T mem.ld -T libs.ld -T sections.ld -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_NAME}.map --specs=nano.specs")

set(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_C_COMPILER> <LINK_FLAGS> -o <TARGET> <OBJECTS>")
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> <LINK_FLAGS> -o <TARGET> <OBJECTS>")
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

# Global definitions
add_definitions(-DDEBUG -DUSE_FULL_ASSERT -DSTM32F051x8 -DHSE_VALUE=8000000)

include_directories(
  # My include directories
)

set(SOURCE_FILES
  # My source files
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

# search for programs in the build host directories
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM   NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY   ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE   ONLY)
```

This is what `arm-none-eabi-size` prints when executed in a console:

```
 $arm-none-eabi-size --format=berkeley "rtos_clion.elf"

 text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 32840     308    7796   40944    9ff0 rtos_clion.elf
```

How would I have that run and have that output displayed in the build window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `TARGET` flow of [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events):

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND arm-none-eabi-size --format=berkeley "rtos_clion.elf")
```

The command will be executed after executable has been (re)built.

Comment: That was quite a lot easier than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a cmake built in variable to get the full command path instead of hard coding? Like there is for objcopy?

Comment: @Ankit: I know no such variable.

Comment: @Ankit You would have to use `find_program` to find and cache the location of the command given some path, hints, and possible names.

Answer (score 3):

Even the `.elf` file can be taken from a variable:

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".elf")
add_custom_command(TARGET ${MAIN_TARGET} POST_BUILD
        COMMAND arm-none-eabi-size --format=berkeley --totals "$<TARGET_FILE:${TARGET}>"
        COMMENT "Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Print Size")
```